# Will I lose my messages if I downgrade my iPhone from iOS 5 to iOS 4?

Tags: iphone

I have found [some resources](http://www.redmondpie.com/downgrade-ios-5-to-4.3.3-4.3.5-on-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-2-ipad-1-ipod-touch-how-to-tutorial/) on how to downgrade my iPhone 3GS from 5.0.1 to 4.3.3. I have saved the required SHSH blobs so I am ready to proceed.

I have a question though - if I do downgrade, will I be able to keep my SMS messages?
Will I be able to restore a backup done on the iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, without a doubt. Unlike with the new ability to update only changes to the OS with iOS 5 delta updates, downgrading your OS will require you to restore the phone. Which essentially reformats the drive.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I clearly understood your answer. Will I lose my messages or be able to keep (restore) them?

Comment: @Xavier under normal circumstances restoring will copy your messages back to the phone but during a downgrade it's very possible that iOS 4 won't be able to restore an iOS 5 backup.

Comment: I can confirm that, I have downgraded and couldn't restore the backup - so messages are lost. It may be possible to restore them manually by digging into the iPhone files/SQLite database but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Good call, good luck!